# Obtain instance weights from AdaBoostM1 in Weka

Tags: java, weka, adaboost

[AdaBoostM1](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/AdaBoostM1.html) is a boosting algorithm implemented in [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).  A key component of this algorithm is the reweighting of "hard to classify" instances after each iteration.  **I want to obtain the weight of each instance that AdaBoostM1 uses for each classifier it constructs**

I have used "[Instance.weight()](http://bio.informatics.indiana.edu/ml_docs/weka/weka.core.Instance.html#weight%28%29)" to obtain instance weights before and after building an AdaBoostM1 model.  The weights do not change and are therefore not what I am interested in.  The source code for AdaBoostM1 is available and it can be seen that weights are set during the construction of a model ([here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/3.6.6/weka/classifiers/meta/AdaBoostM1.java#AdaBoostM1.setWeights%28weka.core.Instances%2Cdouble%29)).   Can the instance weights somehow be obtained before AdaBoostM1 builds each new model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Weka's AdaboostM1 does not have such feature. But you could inherit the AdaBoostM1 class, copy the AdaBoostM1#buildClassifierUsingResampling method from the source, and paste it in your subclass and manipulate the double[] weights variable (as seen in [line 513](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/3.6.6/weka/classifiers/meta/AdaBoostM1.java#513)).